# How to test only latest browser versions with browserstack's local capabilities?

Tags: browserstack

I need to test latest only browser versions with browserstack. My config settings for browserstack-local:

```
  capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'Chrome',
    os : 'Windows'
  },{
    browserName: 'Firefox',
    os : 'Windows'
  }],
```

With 'browser_version : null' I get only random versions being tested. Ist there a setting for latest versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above config snippet just lacks the os_version. In order to run the test on the latest stable version of a specified browser on the OS specified, you need not specify the browser_version capability explicitly. Then by default, the test will run on the latest stable version the browser:

```
var capabilities = {
'os' : 'Windows',
'os_version' : '10',
'browserName' : 'Chrome',
}
```

This would run the latest stable version of Chrome for Windows 10 (Chrome v72 in this case by today).